# Select a point of a curve

Tags: r

I am doing some caclulations with extreme velocities and the only way to solve my system equations is to do it graphically. Once I have plotted my curve, I would like to develop a function that enter an x-value and the function itself plots a line from this x-value up to the corresponding point of the curve and from this point, another line over y-value. Like this I would get my y-value that would be the solution of my system equations. 
Here is my code. The function Vr_Vmed is the expression of my final equation. In fact, n=4 and Tr=50 and x is the variable.

```
par(font=10,font.axis=10,font.lab=10,font.main=11,font.sub=10)
curve(Vr_Vmed(x,n,Tr),xlim=c(1,2.5),ylim=c(1,17),
      xaxs="i",yaxs="i",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",lwd=2,
      xlab="K Weibull",ylab="Vref / Vmed",usr=c(1,2.5,1,17),
      main="Vref Estimation")
axis(1,at=c(seq(1,2.5,0.1)),xaxp=c(1,2.5,1))
axis(2,at=c(seq(1,17,1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add lines to your plot, 
you can use `lines` or `segments`.

```
f <- function(x) {
  y <- Vr_Vmed(x,n,Tr)
  lines(c(x,x,0),c(0,y,y))
}
f(2)
```

(But that does not "solve" anything: your `Vr_med` function
aparently does all the work.)

Comment: Another way of putting this might be: what does your`Vr_Vmed` function return?  If Vincent is too optimistic, and it returns something other than the desired max, there are a variety of peak-finding and "max" functions we could recommend.

Comment: Thanks you very my much.  I know that the solutions is given by Vr_Vmed(x,n,tr) but I need graphical support for my presentation!!